# How to get 'a' tag of id while click that in jquery?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a dynamic a tag in ASP.Net MVC. I want to list the topics according to the menu I clicked with jQuery. And how do I get the value of the clicked `A` element? I tried but it brings the value of the first `A` element. I want the value to come in when it's clicked.

[for example](https://ibb.co/mMJpSm)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="menuKategori">

@foreach (var item in Model.Take(6))
{
    <li><a href="/Home/_PartialKonular/@item.KategoriId" 
id="menu">#@item.KategoriAdi</a></li>


}

<li class="dropdown" id="menudropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>...</b> 
</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       @{ 
           db_sozluk db = new db_sozluk();
           var gelenVeri = db.Kategoris.Where(x => x.KategoriId > 
6).ToList();
       }
        @foreach (var item in gelenVeri)
        {
            <li><a 
href="/Home/_PartialKonular/@item.KategoriId">@item.KategoriAdi</a></li>
        }


    </ul>
</li>
```

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#menuKategori li a').click(function () {
          var gelenVeri = $('#menu').text();

          $.ajax({
              url: '/Home/_PartialKonular/',
              data: { veri: gelenVeri },
              datatype: 'Json',
              type: 'Get'
          })
      })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: What you mean by value of tag ? How is tag rendered ? Do not post images ! post the relevant code which renders your markup

Comment: Can you post your "try code"?

Comment: I uploaded image

Comment: *"I tried it"* ... show us what you tried that isn't working as per [mcve]. We can't help without some code to see what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought there are countless ways to implement this, one approach is using `data-` attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-tab="tab">Tab 1</a>
```

From javascript

```
$("[data-tab]").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert($(event.currentTarget).data("tab"));
});
```

The main problem in your code is that you are not implementing the `event` argument in your click event. It should look something like this:

```
$('#menuKategori li a').click(function (event) {
    var gelenVeri = $(event.currentTarget).text();
}
```

Comment: Though some answers look more simple using just `this`, using `event.currentTarget` is safer when you have another elements (like a span) inside an `A`. if you get use to use currentTarget you will be always safe there.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is wrong, thats why you get always the first "a" text.

Try this one:

```
  $('#menuKategori li a').click(function () {
      var gelenVeri = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should not hard code `id` value for items you are generating in a loop. If your DOM has more than one element with same Id value, that is invalid html. So remove `id="menu"` from the loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(6))
{
    <li>
       <a href="/Home/_PartialKonular/@item.KategoriId">#@item.KategoriAdi</a>
    </li>
}
```

Now to get the clicked item ,you can use `$(this)` in the `click` event. So if you are trying to read the text  you can use the text method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#menuKategori li a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert($(this).text());          
      })
});
```

If you want to use some other value (ex : `KategoriId`), you can set that in html5 data attribute on your `a` tag and read that in your `click` event

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(6))
{
    <li>
       <a  data-id="@item.KategoriId" href="/Home/_PartialKonular/@item.KategoriId">
                      @item.KategoriAdi
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

and you will read it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#menuKategori li a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert($(this).data("id"));          
      })
});
```

If you are trying to call an action method with `KategoriId` value, you can certainly use the `Url.Action` helper to generate the url for you.

```
  <a  data-id="@item.KategoriId" href="@Url.Action("PartialKonular","Home",new { veri=item.KategoriId})">
                      @item.KategoriAdi
 </a>
```

Assuming your `PartialKonular` has a parameter named `veri`. Now for your ajax call, you can use the href attribute value of the clicked link

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#menuKategori li a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var url = $(this).attr("hred");          
         alert(url);

         $.get(url).done(function(response){
            alert("Response received from ajax call");
            console.log(response);
         });
      })
});
```